# text on the spinner has gone to right side in latest android sdk

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

In my android application I have a `Spinner`. problem is come when I check the app in a galaxy not 2 phone. for android version 2.3 and other versions list of items in the spinner are shown in the left side of application. But for latest version first and last arabic strings are shown in right side,
I want all of them to be float to left side like in other devices. Without going for a custom `Spinner` view can't we handle this easily. But if there is no option than going to custom `Spinner`, let me know.

here is the screenshot to get more clear idea.
[image]

Here is the spinner code in xml file

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="262dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small" />
```

Comment: if the only solution is custom view just let me know

Comment: can you please remove android:gravity="left" from the code and try it. By default gravity is set to left side.

Comment: and I want eveythings to align left. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use custom views to handle this. Otherwise nothing help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to your spinner in layout xml :

```
android:gravity="left"
```

Thanks.

Comment: I had set it to centervertical but above problem is appered.I update the question

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/drive_mode"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_down" />

            </TableRow>
```